# Htaccess url rewriting getting numbers

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have some images url like: http://example.com/12345-large_default/image.jpg

And I want to get the 12345 and rewrite to: http://example.com/app/img.php?id=12345

I have tried this and a lot of changes:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\-large_default.jpg$ /app/img.php?id=$1
```

But I can't get it working.

Comment: Try this: `RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)-large_default /app/img.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]`

Comment: No, it doesn't work either :(

Comment: Where is this htaccess located? Provide your full .htaccess in question

Answer (score 0):

Add this rule to your .htaccess file and it will work.

```
RewriteRule ^12345-large_default/image\.jpg$ /app/img.php?id=12345&%{QUERY_STRING}
```